# I can't locate the element but after inspect element manually the code works

Tags: python, selenium

I get this error when I run the code :

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@data-test-id="birth-date__day"]/select"
```

If I inspect Element manually in browser the code works. I was thinking it's because of some frame but can't find it. Also I tried to first click and then try to use "Select"but still not works.

This is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])
driver_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
url = "https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru"
Fname = "John"
Lname = "Micheals"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
day = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-test-id="birth-date__day"]/select')
Select(day).select_by_value("11")
```

Please if someone can help.

Comment: try replacing your call to time.sleep() with a WebDriverWait() instead. (also, confirm your data-test-id value...does it really have two underscore characters in it?)

Comment: Yes it has two underscore characters in it.